# Performance on saving one entity forms with related long collections

Tags: forms, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities

```
EntityA:
  id: ~
  name: ~

EntityB:
  id: ~
  name: ~
  entityA: ~
  unique: [entityA, name]
```

I have around 10000 entities EntityA, when i submit a new EntityB

```
curl -X POST http://localhost/api/entityb.json -d {name: "Hello World", entityA: "017cbc11-95be-4280-8093-9e5b641d73a5"}
```

My bussines logic is pretty simple

```
protected function process(array $parameters, EntityB $object, EntityBType $type, $method = 'PUT')
{
    $form = $this->getFormfactory()->create($type, $object);
    $form->submit($parameters, 'PATCH' !== $method);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->getEm()->persist($object);
        $this->getEm()->flush();

        //... returns 201
    }

    // return 400
}
```

EntityB FormType

```
class EntityBType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('entityA', null, array(
                'property' => 'id'
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ApplicationBundle\Entity\EntityB'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheriDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

EntityB

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull;

/**
 * Class EntityB
 * @package ApplicationBundle\Entity\EntityB
 * @Entity()
 * @Table(
 *      name="entity_b",
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @UniqueConstraint(name="entity_b_uniq", columns={"entity_a_id", "name"})
 *      }
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"entityA", "name"})
 */
class EntityB {
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Id()
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @Column(name="id", length=36)
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(name="name", length=250)
     * @NotNull()
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var EntityA
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApplicationBundle\Entity\EntityA")
     */
    protected $entityA;

    // setter and getters ...
}
```

Take aprox. 2300ms this is too much! in my dev environment a save aprox is 300ms. I think the problem here is when i validate eht entityB with the form fetch all EntityA from database, How i can solve this? the system i'm developing expects between 50000 to 100000 EntityBs

### Executed queries

1. Time: 14.40 ms

   ```
   SELECT 
     t0.id AS id1,  
     t0.name AS name4
   FROM 
     entityA t0
   ```
2. Time: 0.64 ms

   ```
   SELECT 
     t0.id AS id1, 
     t0.name AS name2, 
     t0.entity_a_id AS entity_a_id3 
   FROM 
     entity_b t0 
   WHERE 
     t0.entity_a_id = ? 
     AND t0.name = ?

   Parameters: [017cbc11-95be-4280-8093-9e5b641d73a5, 'Hello World']
   ```
3. Time 0.28 ms

   ```
   SELECT UUID()
   ```
4. Time 0.23 ms

   ```
   START TRANSACTION
   ```
5. Time: 0.49 ms

   ```
   INSERT INTO entity_b (id, name, entity_a_id) 
   VALUES 
     (?, ?, ?)

   Parameters: { 1: fb2dd6c9-3989-11e4-a5d6-1867b083cd22, 2: 'Hello World!', 3: 017cbc11-95be-4280-8093-9e5b641d73a5 }
   ```
6. Time: 240.54 ms

   ```
   COMMIT
   ```

This makes me think the problem is because when you get the list of EntityA, because the timeline in controller show me 2318ms (doctrine uses 289ms from that) and maybe the problem here are the form validator component

Comment: Pasting form classes would be helpful.

Comment: @JakubZalas Add also the entity

Comment: So are you sure all the entity A's are being fetched?  Nothing that you posted suggests that they would.  The add('entityB' in your EntityBType is suspicious but I'm guessing that you are editing stuff after pasting it into the question.  And usually with Symfony I would see things like @ORM\Id.  So I am really wondering what is going on here.

Comment: @Cerad my mistake, i'll add the use statements and the queries executed when i sent a POST request

Comment: Do you have EntityX.orm.yml files?

Comment: @Cerad no i'm using annotations

Comment: Try in prod environment, then activate all doctrine cache and do some improvements in your code (for example removing `$this->getEm()`). Then check what is slower with xhprof. If you want better result try to parallelize all with a GearMan.

Comment: Okay.  Explain why your posted EntityBType has add('entityB' as opposed to entityA?

Comment: @skler in prod take only 100ms less, still it is much

Comment: @Cerad i fixed the EntityBType

Comment: do a [xhprof](http://xhprof.io/) analysis to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I am going to make a leap here and guess that:

```
class EntityBType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('entityB', null, array(
            'property' => 'id'
        ))
        ;
    }
```

Is actually something like:

```
class EntityBType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('entityA', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'EntityA',
            'property' => 'id'
        ))
        ;
    }
```

Setting the type = entity will in fact load the entire EntityA table by default which explains the performance issue.  I always get a chuckle when people post what they think the code should look like as opposed to what it actually is.

To eliminate the default query, follow this:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-choices

Since you already have the EntityA id just query for it then pass it as the choices argument.  I won't try giving you exact code because again, what is in your question does not match your actual code so it would be a waste of time.

But this should get you going.

Comment: when i set null the type, form use the data_class to find the type

Comment: Not relevant.  You are using a type of 'entity' which is what is triggering the unnecessary 'SELECT * FROM entityA' query. Once that query is gone then you should have normal response times.

Comment: There is a big gap in your timing suggesting that the insert operation itself is the culprit.  But I suspect that is just a misleading result of the way you are calculating the time.  Insert a record from your sql command line and verify that the insertion itself is almost instantaneous.  If not then you have an sql index problem of some sort.

Comment: maybe in a short collections of entityA the default 'SELECT * FROM EntityA' is not a problem but when i have a long collection and i know the id is better set a custom code for return the choice

Comment: Which is exactly why I said to query the specific entityA object and then adjust your form to use it instead of the default query.  Read the link I posted.

Comment: i've checked instert the raw query takes 130ms. the problem is was pointed before

Comment: How about in production?

Comment: I write the custom code, now the first query is '... WHERE id = ?' and controller takes 151ms and doctrine 81/151ms in dev :D. thanks @Cerad. I have to stop being lazy and do not always do what has by default :)

Answer (score 0):

doctrine manager isn't really designed to handle more than 1000 entities to save at the same time...

one a good thing to optimize it is to flush every 500 or 1000 entities then clear the doctrine manager or eventually re-create your doctrine manager object.

```
  // your loop through object to save
  $a = 0;
  foreach ( $dataCollection as $data )
  {
     $newB = new entityB();
      ///// settings for entityB
     $entityManager->persist( $newB );
     $a++;

     // we reached 1000 entitiesB so we flush and clear
     if ( $a%1000 == 0 )
      {

         $entityManager->flush();
         $entityManager->clear(); // we clean our entity manager queue
     }
  }
```

Comment: i'm not storing 1000 entities, it's only one

Comment: and if you have a really huge collection to set and be able to read it from a file , i would recommend to create a commande . information here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

Comment: so i didn t undestand your question , sorry